# File-based IPC library/tool

Tags: windows

I'm searching for a tool (ideally including libraries for popular languages) that will allow me to communicate between a sandboxed/restricted environment that allows reading/writing files in specific paths and other tools that require other forms of communication.

I'm a tinkerer and when i use software that some sort of scripting environment i often find myself in situations where things i need are not considered or forgotten about. I would like to leverage the power of other lower-level/more capable languages by using files to redirect what i need to.

Example:

1. ipc tool monitors several directories for "request" files
2. lua environ creates file "request" and writes `run explorer.exe`.
3. lua starts thread waiting for "request" file to be deleted
4. ipc tool picks up on the change and acknowledges recieving the request by deleting the file
5. lua starts thread waiting for "response" file to be created
6. ipc tool runs the inputted command `run explorer.exe`
7. ipc tool creates "response" file in same directory and writes success to it
8. lua thread finds "response" reads it and knows response was successful, deletes
   the "response" file and continues its own execution

Answer (score 0):

I was sick of waiting, so I made my own. In case anyone wants it, [see my GitHub page](https://github.com/Bluscream/file-ipc).